# Backbone.js subviews from existing HTML

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a parent view and a child view, which are not rendered using templates (i.e HTML markup is present for both views)

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: ->
  @parentview = new ParentView
    el      : $("#parent")

app_router = new AppRouter
Backbone.history.start()
```

Parent View :

```
class ParentView extends View
  initialize: ->
  //Calls a method start after an ajax callback
  start: ->
    @child = new ChildView
      el      : $('#child)
return ParentView
```

Child View :

```
class ChildView extends View
  initialize: ->
    blah blah
  events: 
    list of events
return ChildView
```

Events in the parent view fire, but the events in the child view do not. How do I fix this?

Also, is this an acceptable way of using backbone views? Should I render my child view using a template instead?

Comment: Refer to this link : http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this I think you have problem related to binding of functions.

Comment: Yes @RishabhSinghal but it does not seem to be related to the link you provided. The events registered in the child view are not firing.

Comment: That may happen because context('this') when event is fired is not equal to childView. So when it tries to call a method it doesn't find the particular method in context.

Comment: That was pretty much what I gathered from going through other questions on StackOverflow. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can create plunkr or fiddle then I can try to debug it. Your code here doesn't give enough information to actually answer your question.

Comment: Apologies. I was developing in coffee script and there was a stray indentation error. I checked the compiled js to find the  bug. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. I was developing in coffee script and it turns out that there was a stray indentation error. I checked the compiled js to find the bug